# Need help figuring out how to keep a ratio constant between two functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

I'm coding up some custom code for an RPG character sheet, and need some help finding a mathematical formula to use.

Alright, so  I have two sets of two variables.

State 1:  damageTaken1 and maxHP1

State 2: damageTaken 2 and maxHP2

I know for a fact that maxHP1 and maxHP2 will never be equal. (maxHP2 > maxHP1 in all cases).

I am supposed to keep the ratio (damageTaken1/maxHP1) and (damageTaken2/maxHP2) equal.

However, at the same time, both the damageTaken variables are also functions themselves; they will change depending on how much damage the character takes.

What I am trying to find, is how to make the damageTaken functions in order to keep the ratios constant.

To give an example;

In State 1, the character has taken 13 damage, and has a max HP of 26. Thus, the current ratio is 50%.

In State 2, the character has 38 HP. Thus, I want the damage taken to be 19, to keep the ratio 50%.

However, this has to go both ways; if the character is in State 2 and takes 19 damage, I want the damageTaken1 formula to make sure that the character has taken 13 damage in State1.

I hope this makes sense to you! I am supposed to code it on a google docs / excel sheet. I should be able to code it up once I know what I'm actually trying to do, but right now I'm kind of lost.

(I also hope this is the right forum for this)

Comment: I'm guessing it was a typo when you said $14$ was $50$% of $38$...

Comment: Woops, yes, that's an error. Less typo, and more me just derping. I will correct this immediatly.

Comment: What exactly is supposed to change? Just one of the "damage taken" numbers? Say, the 1st is fixed, and you need a formula for the 2nd, given the two HP values? I'm just trying to get a sense of what is fixed (or at least, not something *we* can change) and what we're trying to control.

Comment: The only fixed numbers are the maxHP numbers. Both of the damageTaken are variable.

I need a formula for both damageTaken1 and damageTaken2... Likely, the first will depend on the second, and the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to call the damages $D_1$ and $D_2$, the maximum health points $H_1$ and $H_2$. If I'm understanding the question, then one of your difficulties might be using variable names that are too long to do efficient pencil-and-paper algebra! For programming it makes sense, but mathematically, long names can be rough.

From what you've said, we have $$\frac{D_1}{H_1} = \frac{D_2}{H_2}.$$

We can rearrange this in a number of ways. To get a value for $D_2$, we can multiply both sides by $H_2$, so that

$$D_2 = H_2 \frac{D_1}{H_1} = D_1 \frac{H_2}{H_1},$$

where this last formula highlights that $D_1$ and $D_2$ are always proportional: To go from $D_1$ to $D_2$, just take $D_1$ and multiply by that max health ratio, $\frac{H_2}{H_1}$. The damage taken scales just like maximum health does: To go from $H_1$ to $H_2$, we multiply by $\frac{H_2}{H_1}$, which is the same way to go from $D_1$ to $D_2$.

To go backwards, from $D_2$ to $D_1$, you'll multiply by the reciprocal of the above ratio; you have $$D_1 = D_2 \frac{H_1}{H_2}.$$

If I've misunderstood the question or it's the algebra itself giving you trouble, let me know.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a programmer, hence my descriptive if long-winded variables :P

Lets see... This seems to be very unfortunate for me. This will create a circular dependency (D1 depends on D2, which again depend on D1, etc), which computers *really* don't like.

I may be able to solve it using the built-in scripts though...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'd assumed that at least one of the "damage taken" values would be given/change throughout the game. I've had a mental picture that the player has two modes: regular, and "super" where max health increases, but you want the damage to scale up (or down) with health. So the formulas here just describe how the damage taken changes, when the player switches forms. I'd assumed the actual damage taken would come from some external source, with one value ($D_1$ or $D_2$) known/given at all times.

Comment: Your mental picture is correct. The specific situation is that one player is capable of assuming a dragon form at will. The GM mandated that the HP percentage remains constant between the forms (to avoid Sudden Barbarian Death Syndrome, where the player turns into the form with less health, and promptly keels over dead from the damage).

D1 and D2 would be damage taken in Human and Dragon form separatly. My problem was trying to set up an automated doc that would calculate this for me automatically.  The circular dependency means I can't do it like that though, so I'm writing a script instead.